# installation:how to set freeradius service on startup?

Tags: configuration, installation, centos, freeradius

I have copied from the source using command,
cp /usr/local/sbin/rc.radiusd /etc/init.d/radiusd

now what changes i need to make in /etc/init.d/radiusd?
so that it can autostart?
any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the privileges of radiusd.
 `chmod 755 /etc/init.d/radiusd` ,
 and then start the script by 
`/etc/init.d/radiusd start`
 hope it can solve your problem.